# ¿Cómo leer un .txt y cargarlo en una tabla de sql server?

Tags: sql-server, insert, text

Favor su apoyo con un tema que posiblemente me vayan a pedir y es la de cargar la data de un archivo txt en un tabla 
primero lo que hice fue esto:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempAbono
(
Fila   VARCHAR(MAX) 
);
select * from #tempAbono
BULK insert #tempAbono
from 'E\archivos\150120180530s.TXT'
```

pero me salái este error :

```
 Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\archivos\150120180530s.TXT" could not be opened.   Operating system error code 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)
```

investigando encontré que esto se debía ya que el archivo lo leía desde una ruta local en mi pc y lo que hace la consulta es buscarla en el servidor de la BD

Entonces lo volvía a ejecutar en el servidor de la BD y me sale este error ahora

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\archivos\150120180530s.TXT" could not be opened. Operating system error code 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

el error paso del código 3 al 21, la verdad no se a que se debe esto ya que por lo que entiendo no debería ser tan complicado.

cabe resaltar que el archivo que leo no tiene separadores solo saltos de linea, lo que si no he encontrada es como indicarle la longitud de los campos que quiero en cada fila.

estoy dejando ajunto como una imagen  el archivo que se lee[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: el archivo está en el disco E: dentro del servidor de base de datos?, estás seguro?

Comment: ¿Tienes chance de importarlo usando SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: ¿El usuario del SQL tiene permisos de acceso al disco E?

Comment: @fredyfx es que el archivo ya me llega a mi de esa forma yo no lo genero y estaba revisando los accesos a la carpeta y tiene todo los permisos para el grupo de admnistradores pero no se muy bien a lo que te refieres, me estas consultando acerca de la instancia del sql que utilizo o cúal?

Comment: @Lamak sí el archivo se encuentra en el servidor de base de datos 100% seguro